# What is $query_string set to in case of POST (NGINX)

Tags: nginx

I was going through [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-and-implementing-fastcgi-proxying-in-nginx#important-fastcgi-directives,-parameters,-and-variables) and it says

> `$query_string` or `$args`: The arguments given in the original client
>   request.

will `$query_string` have both get param(as key value after the `?` from the URI) and post body(say json data) depending on the `$request_method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `$query_string` is just the URI parameters.

Information about the body is in `$content_type` and `$content_length`. I don't think you can get the content itself in variables.

Comment: So how does $_POST variable gets the post request body.